# In logic, negation, existentiality and universality of a variable

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I am not sure about it, but does theses two equalities holds ?

$$
\lnot (\forall x, mov(x)) = \forall x,(\lnot mov(x))
$$

$$
\lnot (\exists x, mov(x)) = \forall x, (\lnot mov(x))
$$

Thank you

Aymeric

p.s: mov is just a predicate that stands for movable (mov(x) <=> "x is movable")

Comment: The first one should be: $\lnot (\forall x, mov(x)) = \color{red}{ \exists} x,(\lnot mov(x))$

Comment: ¬∀ is equiv to ∃¬ and ¬∃ is equiv to ∀¬